# problem with laravel 8 : Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

hi i have completed my laravel project locally and i want to upload it on a domain using putty, and i keep getting this type of error :

Error

```
  Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter' not found

  at app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:59
    55|      * @return void
    56|      */
    57|     protected function configureRateLimiting()
    58|     {
  > 59|         RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
    60|             return Limit::perMinute(60);
    61|         });
    62|     }
    63| }

  1   app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:38
      App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::configureRateLimiting()
```

Comment: Go to `app' folder then `config` and open `app.php ` and add the line  `'RateLimiter => Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::class'` under `aliases` .

Comment: thanks for trying to help but that just didn't fix it.

Comment: Have you checked whether that file exists on your server? What have you tried after all to deploy your project?